# Significato di "trovarsi sul mare"

Tags: meaning, difference

I have read the following sentence in an Italian language learning tool:

> Noi pensavamo che il posto si trovasse sul mare.

Does that mean that the place is *on* the sea (eg a petroleum extraction platform, an island) or *by* the sea (= on the coast)?

Comment: By the sea, otherwise it would rather be "in mare".

Comment: As usual, a learning tool that uses the pronoun subject in this case is a bad tool. In standard Italian it is “pensavamo che il posto si trovasse sul mare”. The pronoun subject would be used if there is some opposition: noi pensavamo che…, loro invece che…”.

Comment: AFAIK it is not wrong to use the personal pronoun, only unusual

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, the intended meaning by a native Italian speaker would be the latter, by the sea, on the coast.

You could also say:

> Noi pensavamo che il posto si trovasse *in riva* al mare.

meaning the place is facing the sea is next to the sea.

In the case of the petroleum extraction platform you would say:

> La piattaforma petrolifera si trova *in* mare (aperto).

Comment: What about a fish or a body *in* the sea? "in mare" too?

Comment: You would say _nel mare ci sono i pesci_ e _in mare c'è un corpo_.